# After Deploying the React app the page displayed is black on github pages

Tags: reactjs, github, deployment, github-pages

https://itsmenick.github.io/my-portfolio/  this is my url
I did all the changes regarding the deployment ie changes in script and all but still not reflected in this.

https://github.com/ItsMeNick/my-portfolio/ this is my github path to repository

Can anyone say what is the mistake ?

Comment: I think your homepage redirects to `/my-portfolio` but you don't have any Route for `/my-portfolio` so it does not show anything.

Comment: So what should i do ? Just add a Route for /my-portfolio ?

Comment: Yes, add route for that and display your home page on that route.

Comment: Did but the output is the same

Answer (score 0):

That is odd. and the development build works just fine? I noticed there is a cors error from you github page and this could be your issue.

Comment: What error are you talking can you please explain?